# Why can't I mount hard drive to previous mount point?

Tags: linux, mount, gnome-disks

I reformatted my hard drive and am setting it up using `gnome-disks`. It used to be mounted to `/home/hdd`. Now, it works when I mount it to any location except `/home/hdd`. For example, `/home/hdd1` works.

Why is this and what can I do to mount to `/home/hdd`?

Comment: What error do you get when attempting to mount to `/home/hdd`?

Comment: In `gnome-disks`, I clicked on the "play" arrow to mount and I could see the program processing it but it remained unmounted. No error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue was, but I found a solution:

```
$ mkdir /home/hdd
$ sudo chown username:username /home/hdd/
```

Then I restarted my computer and it worked.